# Is there a keyboard shortcut to multi-select matching strings in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, keyboard-shortcuts, mysql-workbench

I've been reading [MySQL Workbench documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/), and can't find the answer anywhere because I keep searching for "multi-select by string", and since `SELECT` is a function in MySQL, it's not finding relevant results.

Say I have a SQL file that has multiple statements in it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE name = "John" AND job = "dev";
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE name = "Martha" AND job = "dev";
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE name = "Robert" AND job = "dev";
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE name = "Alice" AND job = "dev";
SELECT * FROM tbl_example WHERE name = "Emily" AND job = "dev";
```

This is a very simple example - imagine the actual thing could be hundreds of lines.

What I need to do is change every instance of a certain string, in this case, "dev" to "designer". In some IDE's, there is a shortcut to select one instance, and then hit the shortcut key to multi-select more instances as it finds them. In Sublime, on my Mac, this is <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. In PHP/WebStorm, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. Is there a way to do this in MySQL Workbench?

I've attached a GIF to show what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for a "Search and Replace All" function to edit all occurances of a word in a sql script.  I believe you can get to that easily through the text editor menu system, though I don't have a copy of workbench handy.  The keyboard shorcut, as requested orginally, should be listed with the command, I think.

Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html

Comment: But what if I want to selectively choose the ones to change? Maybe I only want to make a few updates, so I can hit the shortcut keys over and over until I reach the end of what I want to update? Find and replace would find every instance in the file and replace it I think.

Comment: Yes it would.  That is what your graphic is illustrating.  What criteria would you use, then, to decide whether an instance would be changed?

Comment: Are asking how to do a search and replace for one instance, and then repeat/skip further instances manually using a hotkey?  If that is the case, you just need a hot-key for search-and-replace.  Check out  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html

Comment: Yes exactly! Select one instance, and then click the hotkey as many times for each consecutive instance.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for an answer to this question. It may be too late, but I would like to recommend the DataGrip from JetBrains, which allows you to get multiple cursors, change the code style and much more.

https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip
[image: example of multiple cursors]